# How can I set the position of my cursor at the start in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

I have to write a pygame program for a school project and I run into some issues concerning mouse.set_pos.

I need to set the mouse position on the start of my program. Here I have set it to the middle of my little window, but everytime I run it, the mouse is not set to the middle of my window... probably because it is outside the while-loop.

```
[...]

pygame.display.init()

running = True
positions = []
file_contents = {}
click_counter = 1

screen_y = 640
screen_x = 400
pygame.display.set_mode((screen_y, screen_x))
pygame.mouse.set_pos([screen_y / 2, screen_x / 2])

while running:
[...]
```

On the other hand, when I´m trying to use the `pygame.mouse.set_pos([screen_y / 2, screen_x / 2])` inside of my while loop, my cursor is always stuck at the given position.

How do I use `pygame.mouse.set_pos()` in a way so I can only set the mouse position at the start?

Comment: I ran your code with minor changes and it worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you need to call `pygame.mouse.set_visible()` before moving it to the middle (outside the loop).

Comment: The mouse pointer must be in the window, otherwise the position of the muse will not be changed. At least this applies to Windows systems.

Comment: @hippozhipos what did you change to make it work?

Comment: @martineau I tried, but that is not the problem. The mouse is visible when I start the program, it just doesn´t move to the middle

Comment: @Rabbid76 how do I put my mouse pointer inside of my window? By putting it inside of my while-loop?

Comment: @Philipp I know what's the problem, but I have no solution.

Comment: @Philipp Never mind. Looks like my mouse just happened to be in the window.

Comment: Maybe using a third party lib like `pyautogui`, you could use the window position + where you want the mouse to be to position the cursor ?

Comment: @hippozhipos yes I could try that. I think I have to do so if I don´t find another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution if you don't mind using `pyautogui`.

```
import pygame
import os
import pyautogui

winPos = 100
os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS"]= "{},{}".format(winPos, winPos)

pygame.display.init()

running = True
screen_y = 640
screen_x = 400
pygame.display.set_mode((screen_y, screen_x))
pyautogui.moveTo(winPos + screen_y / 2, winPos + screen_x / 2)

while running:
    pygame.event.get()
```